# Studying math master in France

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, education

To people who study higher maths in France, do you write your proofs and solutions in French ?

Or do you just write them in English? I live and study math in Taiwan and we write our proofs in English although prof speaks Chinese in class.

I'm curious about this because I’m planning on studying math master in France and wondering should I need to write French proofs on test or just English is alright? Cuz I’m worried that I’m not rly great in French and even write a math proof, it may be a bit too hard for me.

Comment: At master studies level, English is most often accepted for writing your test/exams in France. The main difficulty you could meet is to understand oral French in lectures, but you can always ask that the lecture is done in English. A majority of lecturers won't have difficulty switching to English

Comment: Ok, I see, I will work on French, thank you so much~ Are the professor’s notes written on blackboard in French ? (Since my profs in class now write their notes in English but speak Chinese. )

Comment: You have to ask individualy to all your assistants to think to write down on a support (blackboard, lecture notes) all the terms that may be difficult to a newcomer. In general, there is a lot of goodwill.

Comment: I see, thank u ~

Comment: I'm not a university professor as @Jean Marie is , but I'm French and I think you should be prepared to follow all courses in French language. My reasons are :  in France there is a strong divide between literary studies and scientific ones, and most of the time ( in France , again) , people with a scientific profile are not at ease with foreign languages, so the probability your math teachers to be reluctant to speak English is rather high ( be they  able to read it for their researches ) ; for the same reason, other students would probabliy not accept the lectures to be given in English.

Comment: As an example, this link showng  that, , at the master level, the required English level is only B2 ( at Strasbourg's university) : <https://mathinfo.unistra.fr/formations/mpa-magistere/magistere/le-descriptif-des-3-annees-de-la-formation/du-magistere-de-mathematiques/rof/FH178/FRUAI0673021VCOEN18159/>

Comment: @Vince Vickler Your remark is true for master studies completely done in a university cursus. As I am more accustomed to master studies done at least partly within an engineering high school (which may be is the case for the OP), I have seen now a real openness to delivering at least mixed lectures : it is now commonplace to have for example lectures with Powerpoint slideshows written in english and talk in french.